# How to convert unmanaged struct to managed and back?

Tags: .net, c, struct, c++-cli, unmanaged

For example, I have a struct:

```
struct values {
    int value1;
    int value2;
};
```

Then I initialize it:

```
struct values *datas = (struct values *) malloc(size * sizeof(struct values) );
```

And filled it.
So, me need to convert few structs to managed, put it into List, delete one struct and convert it back.

Basically, I have few unmanaged structs and I need to delete one with .net and then delete it from memory.

NOTE: Sorry my bad English!

Comment: Are you *really* using managed-c++ in a Visual Studio **prior** to VS2005? Also, why is this tagged C? Are you compiling .c files too?

Comment: Sorry about tag, I use c++/cli. Yes, I compiling .c files too, struct was wrote on c

Comment: A managed struct is incompatible with an unmanaged struct, it has a different layout.  You convert them one field at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my own solution.
For the first I fill the struct

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
        {
            (datas+i)->value1 = i;
            (datas+i)->value2 = i;
        }
```

After, I create the `Class`, which save the data from `datas`

```
public ref class Values
{
private:
    int _value1;
    int _value2;
public:
    Values();
    property int Value1
    {
        int get();
        void set(int value);
    }
    property int Value2
    {
        int get();
        void set(int value);
    }
};
```

So, I can fill the `List` with data from my struct

```
        List<Values^>^ mValues = gcnew List<Values^>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
        {
            Values^ newValues = gcnew Values();
            newValues->Value1 = (datas+i)->value1;
            newValues->Value2 = (datas+i)->value2;

            mValues->Add(newValues);
        }
```

After all, I can remove one of item by the `mValues->RemoveAt(1);`? clear the memory `free(datas);` and recreate struct with new size

```
size = mValues->Count;
datas = (struct values *) malloc(size * sizeof(struct values) );
```

And fill it from List

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Values^ curValue = mValues[i];
            (datas+i)->value1 = curValue->Value1;
            (datas+i)->value2 = curValue->Value1;
        }
```

That's all, I hope it can help someone!